# Arduino relay power supply question

Tags: relay

Hello everyone i got 2 ssr's from here

[image]

([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071CL4VN6))

Sorry about the long link. My question is what power supply should i use. I was thinking a 12v 2amp. On a side note do i look at the input or the output when choosing a power supply

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it's safe for you to work with electricity ...

Comment: May not be but thats why i am here so people can teach me the right way

Comment: it's fine, but a 12v 1A is cheaper and more than enough current for your project.

Answer (score 1):

In the product description it says "DC 12V 8-Channel Relay interface board, and each one needs 15-20mA Driver Current." So 8 times 0.020A is 0.160A per board. I think your 2 amp power supply should work just fine.